# Android TextureView : DrawBitmap only shows the last 2 pixels of each line

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-bitmap

I am making a video conferencing app.

On the NDK Side, I get from the decoder an image in YUV420 so I use http://wss.co.uk/pinknoise/yuv2rgb/ to translate it to RGB8888 into an Android Bitmap.

I then print the bitmap into a surface view.
Everything works, I am happy.

Now I am trying to use a textureview instead of a surfaceview (to simplify the view hierarchy / compositing). And I have a very strange result : only the last to pixels of my bitmap are rendered. And they are rendered in position.

```
Canvas canvas = lockCanvas();
if (canvas == null)
    return ;

canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);
canvas.save();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
canvas.restore();
unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
```

While the texture view should render :

```
|------------------|
|xxxxxx            |
|xxxxxx            |
|xxxxxx            |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
```

This is what it renders.

```
|------------------|
|    xx            |
|    xx            |
|    xx            |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
```

And the strangest is, those two pixel columns are correct. They are the two last pixels of each line of the bitmap. They are rendered correctly at the right place.

Is that a known bug ?

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it was an issue with the alpha component of each pixels.

Calling `setHasAlpha(false)` on the bitmap fixed the issue.